# Calling Generic Method on Generic Field?

Tags: c#, reflection

I have the following and at some point I need to create `Failures` for `Validations`. We suppose each type deriving from `Validation` has one and only one type deriving from `Failure<T>` where `T` is the aforementioned implementation of `Validation`.

As I have a growing number of implementations of `Validation`, I need to be able to instantiate the right type deriving from `Failure<T>,` and call the `link` method on it within a method that looks like

```
void recordFailureForValidation(Validation v) {
   Type failureType = dict[v.GetType()];
   Object failure = Activator.CreateInstance(failureType);
       // how do I call failure.link(v) ?
}
```

At Runtime, a dictionary gives me the type deriving from `Failure<T>` given `T`.
I am able to instantiate `Failure<T>` (`Failure1`, `Failure2`, etc...), but I can't find how to call `link` on the public field `reference` of my newly created `Failure` instance (by making all uses that made sense to me of `GetMethod`, `MakeGenericMethod`, `Invoke`, etc...)

```
public class MyReferenceClass<T>
  where T : Object, new() {
   public void link(T arg) { ... }
}

public abstract class Failure<T>
   where T : ValidationRule, new() {
...
   public MyReferenceClass<T> reference;
...
}

public class Failure1 : Failure<Validation1> {
}

public class Failure2 : Failure<Validation2> {
}


public abstract class ValidationRule {
   ...
}

public class ValidationRule1 : ValidationRule {
...
}

public class ValidationRule2 : ValidationRule {
...
}
```

Comment: Where does the instance of MyReferenceClass<T> come from in your example? That's the one you will be calling the link method on, right?

Comment: yes, I instantiate the class implementing Failure<T>, after which I'd like to call link(v) on it.

Comment: It's not clear where the field comes into it. If you could post a short but *complete* example, e.g. with a hard-coded version, that would really help.

Comment: I have added a couple of lines in the method that I am writing, maybe that defines my issue better ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`link` is private since you do not specify a different accessibility.  Make it `public` or `internal`:

```
public class MyReferenceClass<T>
  where T : Object, new() {
   public void link(T arg) { ... }
}
```

then you can call it from `Failure<T>` through the reference property:

```
public abstract class Failure<T>
   where T : ValidationRule, new()
{
    protected T Validation {get; set;};
    public MyReferenceClass<T> reference;
}

public class Failure1 : Failure<Validation1>
{
    public void Test()
    {
        this.reference.link(Validation);
    }
}
```

Comment: sorry that was a typo. It is actually 'public' in my code. Updated question.

Comment: problem is that I can't cast my instance with (Failure<>)

Comment: What are you trying to cast it to?

Comment: I'd like to cast to (Failure<>), so that I can call "link(v)" on the instance.

Answer (score 1):

Let Failures implement a non generic `IFailure` interface as well as a generic one in the same manner as `IEnumerable` and `IEnumerable<T>`

Create an abstract factory method within `ValidationRule` that has to be implemented by each concrete  Validation

```
public ValidationRule1 : ValidationRule
{
    public override IFailure ToFailure()
    {
        return new Failure1(this);
    }

    ...
}
```